# Fetch data object from onCreateview with Volley

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have a Fragment. it includes Recycler.ViewHolder, Recycler.Adapter and Volley.

```
public class FirstRadiosFragment extends Fragment {

private final static String TAG = FirstRadiosFragment.class.getName();

private TextView mRadiosName;
private RecyclerView mSpinner;

private List<Radios> mRadiosList;
private Radios mRadios;

private SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Button mPlayRadio, mStopRadio;
private Toast mToast;


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    getRadios();

}

/**
 * I saved fragment layout view!
 */



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_activity_main_radio, container, false);

    mRadiosName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_fr_radios_name_fr);
    mSpinner = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_fr_spinner);
    mSpinner.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.radioProgress);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mRadiosList = new ArrayList<Radios>();
    Log.d(TAG, "mRadiosList ---------->: " + mRadiosList.size()); //returns null





    mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    mSpinner.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mSpinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), mRadiosList);

    mStopRadio = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);


    return view;
}


/**
 * Custom Holder For RecyclerView 
 * I will get ArrayList data
 */

private class RadioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mRadioassName;
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Radios mRadios = new Radios();

    public RadioHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_for_spinner, view, false));
        mRadioassName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_items_radios_name);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void bind(final Radios radios) {
        mRadiosName.setText(radios.getRadioName()); 
    }


    private void startPlaying() {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        mStopRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying(Radios radios) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            initMediaplayer(radios);
        }

        mStopRadio.setEnabled(false);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initMediaplayer(Radios radios) {

        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mRadioassName.setText(radios.getRadioURL());

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radios.getRadioURL());

            Log.d(TAG, "initMediaplayer: " + radios.getRadioURL());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
                mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressBar.setSecondaryProgress(100);
                Log.d(TAG, "Buffering ----> : " + percent);
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                if (i == 703 || i == 701) {
                    String InfoMsg = "Bandwith is not strong !";
                    mToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), InfoMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    mToast.show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                String CompMesg = "Success !";
                mToast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), CompMesg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mToast.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getPosition();
        Log.d(TAG, "PlayState" + position);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Staring...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startPlaying();

    }
}

/**
 * Adapter
 */

private class SpinnerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RadioHolder> {

    Context mContext;


    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<Radios> radios) {
        mContext = context;
        mRadiosList = radios;
    }

    @Override
    public RadioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new RadioHolder(inf, parent);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RadioHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Radios radios = mRadiosList.get(position);
        holder.bind(radios);
        holder.initMediaplayer(radios);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRadiosList.size(); //not null
    }


}


// Request !!

public void getRadios() {

    StringRequest mRequestRadios = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, RadiosAmigos.URL_RADIOS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("radios");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Radios radios = new Radios();
                    radios.setRadioID(obj.getInt("id"));
                    radios.setRadioName(obj.getString("radio_name"));
                    radios.setRadioURL(obj.getString("radio_url"));

                    mRadiosList.add(radios);
                    mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RadiosAmigosConfig.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(mRequestRadios);

} }
```

My application works.
I know that Volley is Asynchronous HTTP requests.But The mRadioList I get from the getRadios() method returns null when called in the OnCreateView.However, I get the mRadioList from the Recycler.Adapter perfectly.
I don't understand, Why can not I get mRadioList in the onCreateView?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Volley is asynchronus, that means all the processes will continue without waiting for a response to arrive. When getRadios method is called, you trigger an asynchronys http request, then, almost immediately, onCreateView method is called, but this happens so fast that it is very likely the request is still waiting for a response, hence, your ArrayList will show empty at that precise moment.

That's why Volley has callbacks. Everything you need to do with a response, do it inside the onResponse method. In this case, you're trying to get a list of objects in order to create an adapter and set it to a spinner; just do all this stuff inside the onResponse callback: create the adapter and set the adapter inside the callback method.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I understand what you said.However,I am not trying to get a list of objects in order.I have no problems with the Adapter. The adapter works great. As you said, this happens so fast but the Adapter class is catching a list of object that set mRadioList in getRadios method, and list it.When I called mRadiosList.size() in OnCreateView, The list was null.Why? whereas adapter is still hold all the objects of list.Also when I called getRadios method in OnCreateView, the same thing is happening.